# F# recursive list adding up

Tags: f#

I can't solve this task: fill the list used recursive function. I found the decision like that code but I don't understand how I can to turn its step. this function output [5; 4; 3; 2; 1], but I need [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]. maybe I can use generator something like [1..n] or [for i in 1..n do yield i] but how I should to do recursive call? will be grateful for any advice!

```
let rec dnto = function
  | n when n > 0 -> n::(dnto(n-1))
  | _ -> []
let res = dnto 5
printfn "%A" res
```

Comment: So your task is to write a recursive function that builds a list starting at 1, and ending at a given ``n``? If so, the function you provided is _almost_ what you need, the only thing missing is to reverse the list as the last step.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function that creates a list starting at 1, and ending at a given `n`, might look as follows:

```
let listUpTo n =
    let rec iterDown a i =
        if i <= 0 then a
        else iterDown (i :: a) (i - 1)
    iterDown [] n
```

Since in F# you can only prepend a new element to a list, the most efficient way to go about it is to start at the end, and prepend the next smaller element, and so on until you have prepended 1, and are done.

Comment: thank you again, but my function don't contain list parameter. how I understand my task, it must create a new list each iteration. but I explore your example!

Comment: The function ``listUpTo`` definitely creates a new list each time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

it seems I answered my own question... thank to all!)

```
let rec upto = function
  | n when n > 0 -> (upto(n-1))@[n]
  | _ -> []
let res = upto 5
printfn "%A" res
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the ``@`` operator but it's not efficient, your algorithm will end up having O(n²) time complexity.

Comment: thank for your notice!) I just needed to do this work without its efficiency control. I was interested this question, but I haven't a time to do it... maybe once later, when I get money for this work)

Comment: it was my mentor's task, I hadn't been training decision's efficiency, but solving in given conditions...